# split csv file vertically in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to split a csv file using a bat.

The file is like

```
a;b;c;d;e;f
```

I need to put the columns `a;b` into `file1.csv` and `c;d;e;f` into `file2.csv` using bat language.

this what i done :

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set c=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.csv) do (
  REM this next is just to kill any lingering left-overs
  >f!c!.mol echo.
)
pause
```

Comment: Is that really `DOS` or rather `Windows`?

Comment: it's BAT in windows

Comment: i found a code to split my file but horriztally i need vertically

Comment: I don't understand `i need vertically`. Can you please give an example of expected output?

Answer (score 1):

get the first two columns (`tokens=1,2`) to `file1.csv` and the rest (`*`) to `file2.csv`:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=;" %%a in (file.csv) do (
  >>file1.csv echo %%a;%%b
  >>file2.csv echo %%c
)
```

Comment: If an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) @Stephan Your hint was to unobtrusive 

Comment: More efficient: `(for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=;" %%a in (file.csv) do echo %%a;%%b& >&2 echo %%c) > file1.csv 2> file2.csv`

Comment: @Aacini yes, should be a lot faster, especially with large file(s), but might be confusing for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a .bat file script that splits the .csv file.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content -Path '.\sv.txt' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "if ($_ -match '([^;];[^;]);(.*)') {" ^
                "$Matches[1] | Out-File -FilePath 'sv-file1.txt' -Encoding ascii -Append;" ^
                "$Matches[2] | Out-File -FilePath 'sv-file2.txt' -Encoding ascii -Append;" ^
            "}" ^
        "}"
```